# Нужна помощь с Listview + checkbox

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

У меня проблема с ListView, мне нужно, чтобы по макету сперва идут чекбоксы, а дальше список, клики по чекбоксам фильтруют список

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/prop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Пропущенные"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/prop"
    android:background="@drawable/frame" >

    <!-- the icon view -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tvIcon"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <!-- the container view for the title and description -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tvIcon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <!-- the title view -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

        <!-- the timer view -->
        <Chronometer
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvChronometer"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ArchiveFragment.class

```
public class ArchiveFragment extends ListFragment {
private List<ListViewItem> mItems;        // ListView items list

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new DealsTask().execute((Void) null);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Удаляем разделители из ListView в ListFragment
    getListView().setDivider(null);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Получаем объект theListView
    ListViewItem item = mItems.get(position);
    String[] strArr = item.title.split("/");

    // Делаем что-нибудь.
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass =  DetailFragment.class;

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("suggestion_id", strArr[1]);
    bundle.putString("listActivity", "1");

    assert fragment != null;
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

    ConstantsAPP.active_item = ConstantsAPP.ACTIVE_ORDER_DETAIL;
}

public class DealsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return  new APIweb(getActivity(), false).GetArchiveAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        if(strJson != null) {
            JSONObject dataJsonObj;
            String suggestion_aссepted = null;
            try {
                dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
                JSONArray js_arr = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
                JSONObject error = js_arr.getJSONObject(0);

                if (parseInt(error.getString("error")) == 0) {
                    // initialize the items list
                    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();


                    JSONArray js_arr_suggestion = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("suggestion");
                    for (int i = 0; i < js_arr_suggestion.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject obj_suggestion = js_arr_suggestion.getJSONObject(i);
                        String suggestion_id = obj_suggestion.getString("suggestion_id");
                        suggestion_aссepted = obj_suggestion.getString("suggestion_aссepted");

                        String d_id = obj_suggestion.getString("d_id");
                        String d_type = obj_suggestion.getString("d_type");
                        String d_created_at = obj_suggestion.getString("d_created_at");

                        Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.defaultwork);
                            mItems.add(new ListViewItem(img, d_id + "/" + suggestion_id + "/" + d_type, d_created_at, null, null, null, suggestion_aсcepted));
                    }

                    // initialize and set the list adapter
                    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mItems, R.layout.fragment_archive_listview));

                } else if(parseInt(error.getString("error")) == 1) {
                    setEmptyText("Нет активных заявок.");
                    mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
                    setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), mItems, R.layout.fragment_archive_listview));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

А получается печаль такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А надо то как?.

Comment: Что-бы сверху был чекбокс а снизу список. Я изначально так и написал.

не у каждого итема чекбокс, а чекбокс только сверху лэйаута.

Comment: добавьте `CheckBox` как `Header`

Comment: Я сделал так уже, но не получается зафиксировать чекбокс в топе. Мне нужно чтобы чекбокс не прокручивался.

Comment: Значит не добавляйте его в сам список, а добавьте просто отдельным View в разметку над списком.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы используете `ListFragment`, который по-умолчанию в методе `OnCreateView()` добавляет `ListView`, вам нужно, в первую очередь, переопределить этот метод так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.archive_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Во-вторых написать `archive_fragment.xml`, например так:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Обратите внимание на `id` у `ListView`, он должен быть `@android:id/list`, если вы хотите продолжать использовать `ListFragment`.

В-третьих убрать `checkbox` из `item`'a.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, в итеме уже нет чекбокса